# Is there any way to find Ansible hostname through Client's machine

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I am a beginner in Ansible.

I have one server - app.example.com in which I have installed Ansible.

I have 2 Client machines - Web1.example.com and Web2.example.com.

My question is how I will know from the Client machine that the Ansible server is app.example.com

Like from the Ansible server I can find out all Client's machines in /etc/Ansible/hosts

Comment: Why do you want to know that? What is the use case this is needed for? If you don't explain the context of a question, you risk falling in an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info) situation.

Comment: We have huge numbers of servers in our environment, unfortunately, we don't have access to many servers We can access almost all servers through the Ansible control node but for some servers, we don't know the Control node, so I was trying to find the way out.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know the name of the service account (such as `ansible`) that Ansible uses on the client, and that Ansible has logged in at some time, look in `/var/log/secure`.  You should see an entry like this:

```
Aug 25 09:29:02 Client1 sshd[1343]: Accepted publickey for ansible from 192.168.124.8 port 59036 ssh2: RSA SHA256:FL2me6GmqX6SAx5CI0hJ/ZXXStnmrCdCtBbfBlk5N5E
```

We see is logged in from `192.168.124.8`.

Now...

```
$ getent hosts 192.168.124.8
192.168.124.8   AnsibleTower
```

So the hostname of the Ansible Controller is `AnsibleTower`.